# Trying to plot a system of linear equation using matplotlib in a 2D plane

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

As the title says, I am trying to plot a system of linear equations to get the intersection point of the 2 equations.

8a-b = 9

4a+9b = 7.

below is the code i have tried.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[8,-1],[4,9]])
b = np.array([9,7])
c = np.linalg.solve(a,b)

plt.figure()

# Set x-axis range
plt.xlim((-10,10))
# Set y-axis range
plt.ylim((-10,10))
# Draw lines to split quadrants
plt.plot([-10,-10],[10,10], linewidth=4, color='blue' )


#draw the equations
plt.plot(a[0][0],a[0][1], linewidth=2, color='red' )
plt.plot(a[1][0],a[1][1], linewidth=2, color='red' )

plt.plot(c[0],c[1], marker='x', color="black")

plt.title('Quadrant plot')

plt.show()
```

I get only the intersection point, but not the lines on the 2D plane as shown in the below graph.

[image]

I want something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To plot the lines it's easiest if you rearrange your equations to in terms of `b`. This way `8a-b=9` becomes `b=8a-9` and `4a+9b=7` becomes `b=(7-4a)/9`

It also looks like you were trying to draw the "axis" of the graph, I've fixed this in the code below too.

The following should do the trick:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[8,-1],[4,9]])
b = np.array([9,7])
c = np.linalg.solve(a,b)

plt.figure()

# Set x-axis range
plt.xlim((-10,10))
# Set y-axis range
plt.ylim((-10,10))
# Draw lines to split quadrants
plt.plot([-10, 10], [0, 0], color='C0')
plt.plot([0, 0], [-10, 10], color='C0')

# Draw line 8a-b=9 => b=8a-9
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
y = 8 * x - 9
plt.plot(x, y, color='C2')

# Draw line 4a+9b=7 => b=(7-4a)/9
y = (7 - 4*x) / 9
plt.plot(x, y, color='C2')

# Add solution
plt.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='x', color='black')
# Annotate solution
plt.annotate('({:0.3f}, {:0.3f})'.format(c[0], c[1]), c+0.5)

plt.title('Quadrant plot')

plt.show()
```

This gave me the following plot:
[image]

Comment: Hi @jwalton Thanks for the answer,  how can we annotate the lines with the equation such that it is written parallely to the line?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad this was useful. You could do something like ```plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.annotate('8a-b=9', (-5, 4), rotation=-25)
plt.annotate('1/9(7-4a)', (2.5, 6), rotation=85)
```. Here I chose the rotations chose by eye. However, if you think about your lines you should be able to write down their exact rotation (with respect to the y axis)

Answer (score 1):

```
x1 = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01) # between -10 and 10, 0.01 stepsize
y1 = 8*x1-9

x2 = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01) # between -10 and 10, 0.01 stepsize
y2 = (7-4*x2)/9
```

This is the equations of your lines.

Now plot these using `plt.plot(x1,y1)` etc.

```
plt.figure()
# Set x-axis range
plt.xlim((-10,10))
# Set y-axis range
plt.ylim((-10,10))
# Draw lines to split quadrants
plt.plot([-10,-10],[10,10], linewidth=4, color='blue' )
plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)

#draw the equations
plt.plot(a[0][0],a[0][1], linewidth=2, color='red' )
plt.plot(a[1][0],a[1][1], linewidth=2, color='red' )

plt.plot(c[0],c[1], marker='x', color="black")

plt.title('Quadrant plot')

plt.show()
```